# List Manipulation in python (height)

Tags: python, list

I'm wondering if there is a way to manipulate the size of a 2d list based on user Input. I know the other one like

```
list = [[0*UI],[0*UI],[0*UI],[0*UI],[0*UI]]
```

which will change the length of the list. but i'm wondering if it is possible to manipulate the height of the list

instead of

```
values = [[0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0]]
```

which is a static list is there a way to change both the length and the height of the list based on the user Input?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant way, but you can use a list comprehension:

```
myList = [1,2,3,4]
values = [myList for x in range(n)]
```

Alternatively, you can use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
myList = [1,2,3,4]
it = itertools.repeat(myList, n)
```

Now `it` is an iterator, you can convert it explicitly to a list using `list(it)` or simply iterate over it with a for loop.

Comment: @TenebrisMortem as Paul92 mentioned, this is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

If by height you are referring to how many rows in the 2d list, or in other words, how many sublists are contained inside of the list, you can do that like this:

```
values = [[0] * width for i in range(height)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could, there is the input() function in python.

Also, you can use list comprehension to build the list.

An example for your case would be:

```
x = int(input())

y = int(input())

list = [[i for i in range(x)] for k in range(y)]
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax, perhaps you meant to say `i for i in range(x)` instead?

Comment: True, let me fix it

Answer (score 1):

```
UI = 4
LL = 5
result = [[0] * UI for _ in range(LL)]
result[2][1] = 1
print(result)
```

'UI' controls the length of each sub-list, while 'LL' contains the length of the top list. Note that you have to multiply the length value by a **list** to get a replicated list.

I added the assignment to `result[2][1]`, just to demonstrate that the sub-lists are distinct elements. A simpler way to generate the result, using to list multiplication operations, results in a list of 5 references to the same object, when modifying any of sub-lists reflects in all the others.